# Sorting object by date to display in table view swift

Tags: swift, firebase, uitableview

I have a function that download event objects for a user from Firebase, and I display the event objects in a table view.
Now, I am trying to order the event objects by event date (a field within event object), but for some reason, it is not getting sorted.

When I print the events after my sort function it yields:
Apr 30, 2023
Aug 28, 2023
Aug 30, 2023
May 30, 2023

Which is NOT in order.

```
func downloadEventsFromFirebase(withId: String, completion: @escaping (_ events: [EventObject]) -> Void) {

    var foundEvents: [EventObject] = [] // temp dictionary to store all of the results
    let group = DispatchGroup()

    group.enter()
    FirebaseReference(.Event).whereField(kHOSTID, isEqualTo: withId).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        defer {
            group.leave()
        }
        if let err = error {
            print(err)
        }
        guard let snapshot = snapshot else {
            completion(foundEvents)
            return
        }
        
        if !snapshot.isEmpty {
            for event in snapshot.documents {
                let eventObject = event.data() as NSDictionary
                foundEvents.append(EventObject(_dictionary: eventObject))
                
            }

            //completion(foundEvents)
        }
        else{
            print("no events to fetch")
            //completion(foundEvents)
        }
    }
    
    // This block gets called once all results have been received
    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        // Make one call to the completion handler
        foundEvents.sort(by: { $0.eventDate.compare($1.eventDate) == .orderedAscending })
        for event in foundEvents{
            print(event.eventDate)
        }
        completion(foundEvents)
    }

    
}




// MARK: - Load Events
    private func loadUserData() {
        ProgressHUD.show()
        let currentUser = FUser.currentUser()!
        eventIds = currentUser.eventIdArray ?? []
        FirebaseListener.shared.downloadEventsFromFirebase(withId: currentUser.objectId) { (allEvents) in
            ProgressHUD.dismiss()
            self.eventObjects = allEvents
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.eventTableView.reloadData()
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Of course it's not in order because it sorts the string literally. To be able to sort a date string convert it to `Date` or use a sortable format like yyyy-MM-dd. And stop using `NSDictionary`. This is Swift. And you are misusing `DispatchGroup`. It's for performing multiple asynchronous tasks in a **loop**. You are already using a completion handler, take advantage of it.

Comment: why should I stop using NSDictionary

Comment: Because there is a native type `Dictionary` which is strong typed unlike *objective-c-ish* `NSDictionary`

Comment: Dictionaries (or NSDictionary) are *unordered* groups of objects, and the order can change at any time. To display ordered data, let Firebase do the heavy lifting and present ordered data to your app using `.order(by:`. We don't know how your data is stored as it wasn't included in the question; If dates are stored as Timestamps, then you're good to go. If you're storing as a string it should be `yyyy-MM-dd` format as @vadian mentioned above, along with removing the Dispatch groups as they are not needed. See [Get Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data)